# AngularUI Router - Unable to put ui-view into the desired state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the angular-ui-router to create two nested views (a chart and a table), but unable render anything into these nested views. Here are my top-level views in index.html:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

and here are my nested views in dashboard.html:

```
<section class="dashboard">
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <div ui-view="chart"></div>
    <div ui-view="table"></div>
</section>
```

In response to the url `/dashboard`, the router is correctly pushing dashboard.html into index.html's `content` view. However, I am not able to push anything into the chart and table views even by using `$state.go()`. Here's my router configuration:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app',{
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/header.html'
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/content.html'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: 'dashboard',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardController'
            }
        }

    })

    .state('app.dashboard.chart', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/chart/chart.html'
    })

    .state('app.dashboard.table', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/table/table.html'
    });
```

Here's my attempt to push a chart and a table into the sub-views using `$state.go()` in the DashboardController:

```
angular.module('app.dashboard', ['ui.router']);

angular
    .module('app.dashboard')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['$state'];

/* ----- DashboardController ----- */
function DashboardController($state) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Dashboard';
    $state.go('app.dashboard.chart');
    $state.go('app.dashboard.table');
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the named view vs unnamed state view definition:

The **named** view:

```
<section class="dashboard">
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <div ui-view="chart"></div>
    <div ui-view="table"></div>
</section>
```

The **unnamed** view targeting (here UI-Router is not able to find unnamed view in the above snippet:

```
.state('app.dashboard.chart', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard/chart/chart.html'
})
```

We need to use the view name as well, even in state def:

```
.state('app.dashboard.chart', {
    views: {
      // this view belongs into 'chart' target of its parent
      'chart' : {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/chart/chart.html'
       }
     }
})
```

EXTEND: To get the answer in the comment: *"...the other view is not populated at all. How do I tell `$state.go( )` which view to populate?"*

We can use state navigation to change **states** *(and their views)*, not just the *views*. Other words, **state** in this case, should be filling both views (I'd say).

That means, that we should have something like "details" state

```
//.state('app.dashboard.chart', {
.state('app.dashboard.details', {
    views: {
      // this view belongs into 'chart' target of its parent
      'chart' : {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/chart/chart.html'
       },
      'table' : {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/table/table.html'
       }
     }
})
```

Or we can introduce parent-child

```
.state('app.dashboard.chart', {
    views: {
      'chart' : {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/chart/chart.html'
       },
       // could be even some default for 'table' as well here
     }
})


.state('app.dashboard.chart.table', {
    views: {
      // when inside of a chart, we can go to table to fill even table view
      'table@app.dashboard' : {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/table/table.html'
       }
     }
})
```

SUMMARY: If we need to populate two views, we can do it by parent-child (parent fills one, child the second) or one state should fill both

Comment: Thanks Radim! This is almost working now. The only issue is that both $state.go('app.dashboard.chart') and $state.go('app.dashboard.table') are populating the "chart" view. The other view is not populated at all. How do I tell $state.go( ) which view to populate?

Comment: I see, I would say that this should be changed to logic (if I am not wrong) "When I select one state, it should fill both views"... I will try to extend my answer

Comment: I tried to extend my answer with more details. Hope it helps ;) Good luck with UI-Router

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. I don't know how I could have got these concepts from the docs!